# Python script to transpose dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, transpose

I have a data frame shown here:

```
time    0:15    0:30    0:45
1/1/12  27.84   28.08   27.6
```

I need to transpose it to another dataframe like the one here:
time

```
1/1/12 0:15 27.84
1/1/12 0:30 28.08
1/1/12 0:45 27.6
```

Any idea how I  proceed?

Comment: Have you tried searching for any methods at all?

Comment: If only there were some method called `transpose()`...

Comment: Yes there are tons of ideas. Look at the columns (df.columns), they become a serie that you use, the first row value become another serie and lastly the index or value below time becomes the new index. Put the puzzle together and you are there.

Answer (score 1):

if your df looks like this (df.set_index("time") if it has a separate column for time).

```
df 

time    0:15    0:30    0:45        
1/1/12  27.84   28.08   27.6
```

You can simply:

```
# 1. Create a new DataFrame with two rows (columns and row1) - transpose them.
# 2. Set index to the old index to list and multiply by length of df2

df2 = pd.DataFrame([df.columns,df.iloc[0]]).T 
df2.index = df.index.tolist()*len(df2)
df2
```

Which gives:

```
        0       1
1/1/12  0:15    27.84
1/1/12  0:30    28.08
1/1/12  0:45    27.6
```

---

Works because of this:

```
df.columns # Index(['0:15', '0:30', '0:45'], dtype='object')
df.iloc[0] # array([ 27.84,  28.08,  27.6 ])
df.index.tolist()*len(df.columns) # ['1/1/12', '1/1/12', '1/1/12']
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
a.transpose()
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

## by this way you can transpose using numpy in array in python